# Upload image to S3 using createPresignedPost from flutter app

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

So finally posting this question after spending a whole day trying different things. Scanned the web for everything possible but cannot figure out whats wrong. **Any guidance is appreciated!**

I have a backend which generates the presigned url using this:

```
await createPresignedPost(s3Client, {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: `${currentUser.uid}/${fileContext}/${fileContextId}/${fileName}`,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds || 900, // S3 default is 900 seconds (15 minutes)
  });
```

Then I try to upload the file using postman and it uploads fine

[image: postman]

.

However when I try to upload the file using Flutter app on a physical android device I get the error

```
   Future<void> uploadImage(XFile imageFile) async {
    try {
      final signedUrlParams = await getPreSignedUrlFromServer(
        fileName: imageFile.name,
        fileContext: 'xyz',
        fileContextId: id,
      );

      final uri = Uri.parse(signedUrlParams['url']);
      final httpImage =
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(imageFile.name, imageFile.path);

      var uploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', uri);

      uploadRequest.files.add(httpImage);

      uploadRequest.headers.addAll({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      });

      uploadRequest.fields.addAll({
        "bucket": signedUrlParams["fields"]["bucket"],
        "key": signedUrlParams["fields"]["key"],
        "X-Amz-Algorithm": signedUrlParams["fields"]["X-Amz-Algorithm"],
        "X-Amz-Credential": signedUrlParams["fields"]["X-Amz-Credential"],
        "X-Amz-Date": signedUrlParams["fields"]["X-Amz-Date"],
        "X-Amz-Security-Token": signedUrlParams["fields"]
            ["X-Amz-Security-Token"],
        "Policy": signedUrlParams["fields"]["Policy"],
        "X-Amz-Signature": signedUrlParams["fields"]["X-Amz-Signature"],
      });

      final response = await uploadRequest.send();

      if (response.statusCode != 204) throw Exception();
    } catch (err) {
      throw ('Error uploading image: $err');
    }
  }
```

This is the error that I get

```
response status code: 403
response header: {connection: close, transfer-encoding: chunked, date: Sun, 04 Sep 2022 20:02:17 GMT, x-amz-request-id: 5QH13MNXZXBV3T, content-type: application/xml, x-amz-id-2: 7X8S3tLat9hRpMfBk/xrYTKavWuc7emeOlp1YASH+/oKvNfM=, server: AmazonS3}
response reason: Forbidden
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw your http request.

Your AWS presigned url request method was **POST**.
But in flutter you are using **PUT** method.

> change it to POST method and try again